# Does it make sense to write addition test for a method if it is already covered by another test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, test-coverage

I am testing my spring boot application with unit tests and in coverage report, I have +85% branch coverage. There are some cases where some methods are covered while testing other methods such as mappers, utility methods, etc.

For example, in the service method, I called mapper and utility methods, and those methods are marked as covered in the coverage report because I tested that service method.

My question is, does it make sense to write additional tests for those mapper and utility methods since they are already covered in the service tests?

Comment: well ~ if one of your methods fails - will you be able to tell which has failed from your method?

Comment: No, if the service method test fails, I don't know if it is because of utility, mapper or some inline logic.

Comment: Unit tests should test each individual *unit* or component - so I would say it's best to try and write unit tests for the individual methods - and then have your service method test. Double coverage will be "safer" than cutting corners. But still, you're doing 85% better than those who do **no** unit testing. :)

Comment: I agree that you should "test *it."*  If another test happens to "cover it," to me that's coincidental.  For each thing, you should have tests which adequately exercise that thing, and which are explicitly associated with that thing.  If a particular piece of code thereby gets "covered" more than once, that's fine.

Comment: "*There are some cases where some methods are covered while testing other methods*" - You should be mocking those called you believe are being covered. Imagine you were testing those other methods, and they failed due to the "covered" method. Testing both together would be testing their integration, not the units themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually take a different approach that I would like to share.

Say, I'm a developer that has got the task to create a Mapper or utility.
At this time the Service doesn't even exist.

I write my code, but then I want to check myself. So I unit test it. I don't care about the coverage at this point, for me, coverage is a tool that helps me to understand and decide whether I've made all the checks I need or I've missed an area in a code of Mapper that I wrote that possibly has a bug.

So I've made sure that my code is perfect and I submit it and move to another task...

Later (weeks, months, years) someone, me or another programmer, creates a Service that uses my code. Lets pretends its you, for example.

So you basically don't care about Mapping code, you assume that it works. However you do want to check your Service, and so you write your unit tests that can mock the dependency  on Mapper or run it within the test if its not a real dependency and its fast and everything. Again you don't care about the overall coverage, you care about your code, you want to make sure that your code doesn't have bugs, and again, coverage helps you make sure that you've done your best to check your code before it meets production.

As for my old tests of Mapper - well, they're still run.

Bottom line I don't think that code should be covered for the sake of coverage, but tests (and coverage) should provide you a safety net if you wish.

With this in mind, You should write tests for your code, if you can mock other dependencies be it, if not - just run them.

P.S. I believe there might be many different opinions of this, so there is no one single right answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

Do not write unittests to "cover code".
**Write unittests to *verify behavior*.**
The number of tests executing a certain line of production code does not have any meaning.

Also unittests test a unit (an arbitrary piece of code) **in isolation**. That means if the *code under test* uses  other units as *dependencies* these other units should be replaces by *test doubles* (such as stubs, fakes or mocks) during the unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does . Unit tests are not just for coverage . Coverage is one part of it . Your main aim is to write unit tests to avoid or minimize the bugs from testers or from production . 
You should test your function with all sort of negative scenarios and positive scenarios . 
apart from these you should test boundary conditions of your code .